# Move camera to fit 3D scene

Tags: 3d, zooming, perspective

I'm looking for an algorithm to fit a bounding box inside a viewport (in my case a DirectX scene). I know about algorithms for centering a bounding sphere in a orthographic camera but would need the same for a bounding box and a perspective camera. I can not just change the FOV because this app has FOV as a user editable variable, so it must move the camera.

**I have most of the data:**

- I have the up-vector for the camera
- I have the center point of the bounding box
- I have the look-at vector (direction and distance) from the camera point to the box center
- I have projected the points on a plane perpendicular to the camera and retrieved the coefficients describing how much the max/min X and Y coords are within or outside the viewing plane.

**Problems I have:**

- Center of the bounding box isn't necessarily in the center of the viewport (that is, it's bounding rectangle after projection).
- Since the field of view "skew" the projection (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Perspective-foreshortening.svg) I cannot simply use the coefficients as a scale factor to move the camera because it will overshoot/undershoot the desired camera position

How do I find the camera position so that it fills the viewport as pixel perfect as possible (exception being if the aspect ratio is far from 1.0, it only needs to fill one of the screen axis)?

**I've tried some other things:**

- Using a bounding sphere and Tangent to find a scale factor to move the camera. This doesn't work well, because, it doesn't take into account the perspective projection, and secondly spheres are bad bounding volumes for my use because I have a lot of flat and long geometries.
- Iterating calls to the function to get a smaller and smaller error in the camera position. This has worked somewhat, but I can sometimes run into weird edge cases where the camera position overshoots too much and the error factor increases. Also, when doing this I didn't recenter the model based on the position of the bounding rectangle. I couldn't find a solid, robust way to do that reliably.

Help please!

Comment: Solved similar problem (in three.js), with live code snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923651/how-can-a-3d-box-with-unequal-sides-fill-the-viewport-no-matter-its-orientation/38001752#38001752

Answer (score 41):

There are many possible camera positions + orientations where the bounding box would fit inside the view frustum. But any procedure would select one specific camera position and orientation.

If you *would* consider bounding spheres, one solution could be to

- first change orientation to look at bounding sphere center
- then move back sufficiently (negative look direction) for bounding sphere to fit inside frustum

With *bounding boxes* you could consider an earlier step of first positioning the camera at perpendicular to the center of the largest (or smallest, whatever you prefer) cube face.

I have no experience with DirectX, but moving and changing the looking direction of the camera to center a certain point should be easy.
The hard part is to do the math of deciding how far to move to view the object.

#### Math

If you know the bounding size `s` of the object in world coordinates (we are not interested in pixels or camera coordinates, since those are dependent on your distance) from the orientation of the camera, you can compute the required distance `d` of the camera to the bounding shape if you know the x and y Field-Of-View angle `a` of the perspective projection.

```
     frustum      ------            
            ------    *****          -  
       -----          *   *          |
   -===     ) FOV a   *bounding box  | BB size s
camera -----          *   *          |
            ------    *****          -
                  ------
  
  |-------------------|
        distance d
```

So, the [math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Tangent) is `tan(a/2) = (s/2) / d` => `d = (s/2) / tan(a/2)`
Which will give you the distance the camera should be placed from the closest bounding surface.

Comment: Just for clarification: S is the size along the longest axis and A is the FOV for the same axis (since FOV differs depending on aspect ratio)?

Comment: Also: How do I easiest center the bounding rectangle? Unlike a bounding sphere, looking at the center of a bounding box does not produce a centered bounding rectangle, and due to the perspective, simply just measuring the offset of the bounding rectangle from screen coords does not give me a good scalar for moving the camera.

Comment: first question: yes, that is correct.
second question: that's why I proposed to just put the camera first directly perpendicular to one of the BB surfaces. From that position, that surface will (even with perspective) be the constraining BB shape.

Answer (score 16):

I know there are some excellent answers above, but I wanted to add a rediculously simple solution to fit the bounding *sphere* inside the camera frustrum. It makes the assumption that you want to keep the camera Target and Forward vector the same, and simply adjust camera distance to target.

***Note,*** this won't give you the best fit but it will give you an approximate fit, showing all geometry, and only in a few lines of code, and without screen to world transformations

[image]

```
// Compute camera radius to fit bounding sphere
// Implementation in C#
// 

// Given a bounding box around your scene
BoundingBox bounds = new BoundingBox();

// Compute the centre point of the bounding box
// NOTE: The implementation for this is to take the mid-way point between 
// two opposing corners of the bounding box
Vector3 center = bounds.Center;

// Find the corner of the bounding box which is maximum distance from the 
// centre of the bounding box. Vector3.Distance computes the distance between 
// two vectors. Select is just nice syntactic sugar to loop 
// over Corners and find the max distance.
double boundSphereRadius = bounds.Corners.Select(x => Vector3.Distance(x, bounds.Center)).Max();

// Given the camera Field of View in radians
double fov = Math3D.DegToRad(FieldOfView);

// Compute the distance the camera should be to fit the entire bounding sphere
double camDistance = (boundSphereRadius * 2.0) / Math.Tan(fov / 2.0);

// Now, set camera.Target to bounds.Center
// set camera.Radius to camDistance
// Keep current forward vector the same
```

The implementation of BoundingBox in C# is found below. The important points are the Centre and Corners properties. Vector3 is a pretty standard implementation of a 3 component (X,Y,Z) vector

```
public struct BoundingBox
{        
    public Vector3 Vec0;
    public Vector3 Vec1;

    public BoundingBox(Vector3 vec0, Vector3 vec1)
    {
        Vec0 = vec0;
        Vec1 = vec1;
    }

    public Vector3 Center
    {
        get { return (Vec0 + Vec1)*0.5; }
    }

    public IList<Vector3> Corners
    {
        get
        {
            Vector3[] corners = new[]
            {
                new Vector3( Vec0.X, Vec0.Y, Vec0.Z ), 
                new Vector3( Vec1.X, Vec0.Y, Vec0.Z ), 
                new Vector3( Vec0.X, Vec1.Y, Vec0.Z ), 
                new Vector3( Vec0.X, Vec0.Y, Vec1.Z ), 
                new Vector3( Vec1.X, Vec1.Y, Vec0.Z ), 
                new Vector3( Vec1.X, Vec0.Y, Vec1.Z ), 
                new Vector3( Vec0.X, Vec1.Y, Vec1.Z ), 
                new Vector3( Vec1.X, Vec1.Y, Vec1.Z ), 
            };

            return corners;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should multiply "boundSphereRadius" by 2 when calculating "camDistance".

Answer (score 6):

Since you have a bounding box, you should have a basis describing it's orientation.  It seems that you want to position the camera on the line coincident with the basis vector describing the smallest dimension of the box, then roll the camera so that the largest dimension is horizontal (assuming you have OBB and not AABB). This assumes that the aspect ratio is greater than 1.0; if not you'll want to use the vertical dimension.

What I would attempt:

1. Find the smallest box dimension.
2. Find the associated basis vector.
3. Scale the basis vector by the distance from the center of the box the camera should be. This distance is just `boxWidth / (2 * tan(horizontalFov / 2))`. Note that `boxWidth` is the width of the largest dimension of the box.
4. Place the camera at `boxCenter + scaledBasis` looking at the `boxCenter`.
5. Roll the camera if necessary to align the camera's up vector with the appropriate box basis vector.

**Edit:**

So I think what you're getting at is that you have the camera at an arbitrary position looking somewhere, and you have an AABB at another position.  Without moving the camera to face a side of the box, you want to:

- Look at the center of the box
- Translate the camera along it's look vector so that the box takes the maximum amount of screen space

If this is the case you'll have a bit more work; here's what I suggest:

1. Rotate the camera to look at the center of the bounding box.
2. Project all the points of the box into screen space and find the min/max bounding box in screen space (you already have this).
3. Now `Unproject` two opposing corners of the screen space bounding box into world space.  For a Z value use the *closest* world space points of your AABB to the camera.
4. This should get you a world space plane facing the camera positioned at the point on the AABB that is closest to the camera.
5. Now use our existing side-facing method to move the camera to the appropriate spot, treating this plane as the side of your box.

Comment: The boxes are AABB, but that shouldn't really matter. I have the bounding rectangle as projected onto a plane perpendicular to the camera.

It seems like you are trying to design around the problem by "hiding" the morphing done by the perspective matrix. Am I right? That solution wouldn't work for me. I need to view at it at the same angle as before the "zoom to fit" command. What I'm looking for is how to factor in the non-linear scaling of the bounding rect when I move along the Camera-Z.

Comment: My answer is fundamentally the same as catchmeifyoutry's answer (our distance math is the exact same).  Using our method the perspective is taken care of by positioning the camera at the proper distance from the side of the box.

Comment: I agree with Ron, we basically suggested the same method. Adapted approaches are possible such as computing a new BB aligned with the camera's coordinate system, or what Ron suggested later (+1 for that).

Comment: I like your idea of transforming the current AABB into camera space and constructing a camera-axis-aligned BB; this would reusing the existing AABB code and wouldn't necessitate hopping between screen space/back repeatedly.

Comment: Yes, it looks like step 3 in the edit was what I was looking for. If I need to center the bounding rect (i.e by panning the camera) this shouldn't interfere with the Unproject, right?

I will test this next week when at the office and mark this as the correct answer if it works.

Comment: Panning the camera could cause part of the box to be clipped (slightly) due to the perspective transform. Any time you move your camera relative to the projected plane you'll need to recalculate it unless you're just moving directly along the plane normal. Luckily the calculation is pretty simple so you should be able to do this without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have it at hand at the moment but the book you want is [http://www.amazon.com/Jim-Blinns-Corner-Graphics-Pipeline/dp/1558603875/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpi_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558603875)

He has a whole chapter on this

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have a crude implementation in place but will look into his version to see if it is a more elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

This is copied straight from my engine, it creates 6 planes which represent each of the six sides of the frutsum.
I hope it comes in useful.

```
internal class BoundingFrustum
    {
        private readonly float4x4 matrix = new float4x4(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        private readonly Plane[] planes;

        internal BoundingFrustum(float4x4 value)
        {
            planes = new Plane[6];
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                planes[i] = new Plane();
            Setfloat4x4(value);
        }

        private void Setfloat4x4(float4x4 value)
        {
            planes[2].Normal.X = -value.M14 - value.M11;
            planes[2].Normal.Y = -value.M24 - value.M21;
            planes[2].Normal.Z = -value.M34 - value.M31;
            planes[2].D = -value.M44 - value.M41;
            planes[3].Normal.X = -value.M14 + value.M11;
            planes[3].Normal.Y = -value.M24 + value.M21;
            planes[3].Normal.Z = -value.M34 + value.M31;
            planes[3].D = -value.M44 + value.M41;
            planes[4].Normal.X = -value.M14 + value.M12;
            planes[4].Normal.Y = -value.M24 + value.M22;
            planes[4].Normal.Z = -value.M34 + value.M32;
            planes[4].D = -value.M44 + value.M42;
            planes[5].Normal.X = -value.M14 - value.M12;
            planes[5].Normal.Y = -value.M24 - value.M22;
            planes[5].Normal.Z = -value.M34 - value.M32;
            planes[5].D = -value.M44 - value.M42;
            planes[0].Normal.X = -value.M13;
            planes[0].Normal.Y = -value.M23;
            planes[0].Normal.Z = -value.M33;
            planes[0].D = -value.M43;
            planes[1].Normal.X = -value.M14 + value.M13;
            planes[1].Normal.Y = -value.M24 + value.M23;
            planes[1].Normal.Z = -value.M34 + value.M33;
            planes[1].D = -value.M44 + value.M43;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                float num2 = planes[i].Normal.Length();
                planes[i].Normal = planes[i].Normal / num2;
                planes[i].D /= num2;
            }
        }

        internal Plane Bottom
        {
            get { return planes[5]; }
        }
        internal Plane Far
        {
            get { return planes[1]; }
        }
        internal Plane Left
        {
            get { return planes[2]; }
        }
        internal Plane Near
        {
            get { return planes[0]; }
        }
        internal Plane Right
        {
            get { return planes[3]; }
        }
        internal Plane Top
        {
            get { return planes[4]; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else interested on a more precise solution, I did this one for 3ds Max cameras. To fit any amount of objects on the camera view. You can see the Maxscript code as seudo-code can be easy to read, and there are some helpful comments.

https://github.com/piXelicidio/pxMaxScript/tree/master/CameraZoomExtents

What I did for simplification is to work on camera space. Getting object vertices or Bounding box vertices and projecting on two 2D planes.

The first is like seeing your camera from top view (The Horizontal FOV)
The second is from side view (The Vertical FOV)

Projects all the vertices on the first plane (the top view)
Now take two lines coming from the camera position, representing the camera FOV, one for the Left side, and other for the Right side. We need only the direction of this line.

[image]

Now we need to find a point (vertex) than if we draw **right line** over it, all other points will fall at the left side. (Found the red dot on the figure)

Then find another ponit that if the **left line** goes over it, all other points fall on the right side of the line. (The blue dot)

With those to points then we intercept the two lines passing trough those two points (We are still in 2D).

The resulting interception is the best position of the camera to fit the scene taking only into account the horizontal FOV.

Next do the same for the vertical FOV.

These two position will give you all you need to decide if the fit needs to be from the sides or form top and bottom.

The one that gives the camera more translation moving away form the scene is the one to get the "perfect fit", the other one will have more empty room then you need to find the center... which is calculated also on the script on the link above!

Sorry can't keep explaining need to sleep now ;) If someone is interested, ask and I'll try to extend the answer.

Comment: +1 This was the most precise solution for me that found the perfect camera placement in a single shot, no iterations needed at all. I've worked in 3D space though, no need to temporarily convert to 2D space. See implementation in Unity/C#: https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityRuntimePreviewGenerator/blob/7a3b44b07949f712010b680b9f2c499e5aa2ebc1/Plugins/RuntimePreviewGenerator/RuntimePreviewGenerator.cs#L416-L441

Answer (score 0):

Check this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197900.aspx

float distance = sphere.radius / sin(fov / 2);

float3 eyePoint = sphere.centerPoint - distance * camera.frontVector;