# Three.js - Algorithm to set the camera so the whole scene shows?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

When I setup my scene, add geometries etc, how do I set the camera so I can see my whole scene? I'm trying to implement an algorithm using boundingboxes, but I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: Please post some examples on jsfiddle.
And be more specific next time.

Comment: If i had some code, it would be posted, but I don't know how to proceed...I'm still thinking :(. My scene would have n meshes, with different widths, heights and depths. I want to find the "best fit" camera position, which shows all the meshes.

Comment: Please try first. Then, if you have problems, post your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: How can I begin trying? I'm asking help with the algorithm...how can I implement something If I don't know how to begin?

Comment: You _do_ know how to begin. You just don't know how to _finish_. :-)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866350/move-camera-to-fit-3d-scene

Comment: @WestLangley that's right :P

Answer (score 0):

You really only need to find the greatest absolute value between all your variables by using `Math.abs(number)`, once you have found the greatest of all you can set the depth(position.z) of the camera to that number. I have made a simple function which receives 2 numbers and returns the greatest.

```
function findGreatestAbsolute( firstNumber, secondNumber ) {
    if( Math.abs( firstNumber ) > Math.abs( secondNumber )) {
        return Math.abs( firstNumber );
    } else { return Math.abs( secondNumber ); }
}
```

You can also use Arrays if there are too many numbers.
Once you have found your number you do:

```
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( cameraFov, windowHalfX / windowHalfY , 1, someDepth );
    camera.position.z(greatestNumber);
```

or

```
    camera.position.set(yourX, yourY, greatestNumber);
```

Well I hope it helps.