# How to calculate in babylon.js the camera position to the loaded model intermeddle in screen?

Tags: javascript, webgl, screen, scaling, babylonjs

I need to boot the entire model got completely into the viewport.
[image]
Because if the model has a large size, it does not got completely into the viewport, for example:

[image]

To solve this problem I need set the desired camera position:

```
camera.setPosition( new BABYLON.Vector3(216, 93, -17) );
```

for example: 
[test page](http://178.62.253.28)

How do I automatically calculate the coordinates of the camera in which the model will got completely into the viewport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move camera to fit 3D scene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866350/move-camera-to-fit-3d-scene)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set:

```
camera.parent = yourMesh;
```

Then you can change: `camera.position` like you want

But note that: the camera is parent so the position is relative to his parent!

So you can't simply use your vector: (216, 93, -17)