# How PowerPoint 3D engine calculate scaling factor of 3D models (am3d:meterPerModelUnit)

Tags: 3d, powerpoint, openxml

I want to add **3D models** into **PowerPoint** presentation using **OpenXML**.
When I add 3D models in GLB format, into an empty presentation, and then extract its XML contents, I can see so many parameters which are started with **am3d** tags, and one of them is **meterPerModelUnit**:

***<am3d:meterPerModelUnit n="8069447" d="1000000"/>***

When I increase this number (and save and zip again) the model will be zoomed in and when I decrease it the model will be zoomed out. Also when I reset the model the value will be reset automatically to this constant number for my specific model.

According to [microsoft office model 3d schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-odrawxml/01138e0c-752b-46fa-bccc-f714ab944ef5), this is the **scaling factor** used in **GLB** file but I couldn't figure out the mathematics behind this ratio calculation in **3D Models** and/or **PowerPoint** 3D Engine. Does anyone know how the meterPerModelUnit parameter is calculated when the model is inserted in **PowerPoint**?!

Comment: You might be able to get an answer asking Microsoft directly here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/openspecs-office-fileformats.html

Comment: Hey Todd thanks for your reply, it was very helpful. For anyone who wants to know the answer, take a look at here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/668824/how-powerpoint-3d-engine-calculate-scaling-factor.html